# Is there any way to get variable importance with Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

I am looking for a proper or best way to get variable importance in a Neural Network created with Keras. The way I currently do it is I just take the weights (not the biases) of the variables in the first layer with the assumption that more important variables will have higher weights in the first layer. Is there another/better way of doing it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since everything will be mixed up along the network, the first layer alone can't tell you about the importance of each variable. The following layers can also increase or decrease their importance, and even make one variable affect the importance of another variable. Every single neuron in the first layer itself will give each variable a different importance too, so it's not something that straightforward.

I suggest you do `model.predict(inputs)` using inputs containing arrays of zeros, making only the variable you want to study be 1 in the input.

That way, you see the result for each variable alone. Even though, this will still not help you with the cases where one variable increases the importance of another variable.

Comment: I was wondering if we could use random forest feature importances from sklearn and then use the important features evaluated by it to the keras classifier. Does this create a problem?

Comment: @deadcode probably yes, since random forest is a decision tree algo totally different from nn's

Comment: You should really shuffle the variable among your sample instead of setting things to zero. This preserves mean and variance of inputs.

Comment: @Teque5 A good point of 'preserving mean and variance of inputs'. This shuffling method is called permutation importance for random forest. There is a package to do it: https://github.com/parrt/random-forest-importances. But I am not sure if permutation importance applied to NNs and deep learning models.

Comment: Take a look at the section **Feature Importance Evaluation** of this paper http://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/scipy2019/pdfs/aero_ef_logue.pdf for an in-depth discussion of variable importance methods.

Comment: @Teque5 What about instead of shuffling the feature setting it values to random numbers (between 0 and 1, or similar, depending on the scaling)? Will this also be reasonable?

Comment: @NeStack The whole point of shuffling is to keep a representative population for that particular parameter. I haven't tested randomizing the input but I expect it would be similar to setting it to 0 uniformly. Both methods would deviate significantly from the model's expected input.

Comment: @Teque5  , I think that randomizing may be good "as long as you use the SAME values for all samples". Then you compare the zeros, the ones, the randoms, whatever, varying only the desired variable. This might answer whether the importance of this var is more or less affected by the others.

Comment: @DanielMöller can you provide an example of that? Not too sure what you mean by randomizing if in the end you use the same values for all samples...

Comment: I understand that we want to drop some features if they are not useful, but say if we don't need to drop the features, would neural network handle the feature importance automatically ?  Can we run the model with another algo, eg in sklearn to check the feature importance as an initial guess, then use tf nn to do the actual model ?

Answer (score 19):

*Edited to include relevant code to implement permutation importance.

I answered a similar question at [Feature Importance Chart in neural network using Keras in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361559/feature-importance-chart-in-neural-network-using-keras-in-python/52410345#52410345).  It does implement what [Teque5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/760099/teque5) mentioned above, namely shuffling the variable among your sample or permutation importance using the [ELI5 package](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html).

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier, KerasRegressor
import eli5
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance

def base_model():
    model = Sequential()        
    ...
    return model

X = ...
y = ...

my_model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=basemodel, **sk_params)    
my_model.fit(X,y)

perm = PermutationImportance(my_model, random_state=1).fit(X,y)
eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = X.columns.tolist())
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20906507)

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I first considered copying my answer from the first link where I answered a similar question with a code example, but researched to find that was bad form.  In this case my first link goes back to a similar stack overflow question.  Is it ok to be link-only answer if a more complete answer is referenced directly from stack overflow?

Comment: As a norm, link only answers needs to be provided via comment.

Comment: I have multiple features and getting `TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method. The estimator <keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x7fb2277e50b8> does not.`

Comment: @Enthusiast add a score method as follows:  
perm = PermutationImportance( model, scoring="accuracy", random_state=1).fit(

Answer (score 8):

It is not that simple. For example, in later stages the variable could be reduced to 0.

I'd have a look at [LIME](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05386) (Local Interpretable Model-Agnostic Explanations). The basic idea is to set some inputs to zero, pass it through the model and see if the result is similar. If yes, then that variable might not be that important. But there is more about it and if you want to know it, then you should read the paper.

See [marcotcr/lime](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) on GitHub.

Comment: LIME permutes the covariates around a single observation and predicts output using the trained model. Then a weighted local-linear regression is fit to the model outputs and the permuted covariates (for regression anyway). This returns a coefficient for each observation. It does not attempt to explain global behaviour although that is something you can easily do by running LIME for every observation and examining the coefficients. I do not see how the above explanation is related to lime as it seems to describe a classic sensitivity analysis.

Answer (score 7):

This is a relatively old post with relatively old answers, so I would like to offer another suggestion of using [`SHAP`](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) to determine feature importance for your Keras models. `SHAP` also allows you to process Keras models using layers requiring 3d input like `LSTM` and `GRU` while `eli5` cannot.

To avoid double-posting, I would like to offer [my answer to a similar question on Stackoverflow on using `SHAP`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61861991/5305519).