# Feature Importance Chart in neural network using Keras in Python

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am using python(3.6) anaconda (64 bit) spyder (3.1.2). I already set a neural network model using keras (2.0.6) for a regression problem(one response, 10 variables). I was wondering how can I generate feature importance chart like so:

[image: feature importance chart]

```
def base_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=10, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
    return model

clf = KerasRegressor(build_fn=base_model, epochs=100, batch_size=5,verbose=0)
clf.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

Answer (score 41):

I was recently looking for the answer to this question and found something that was useful for what I was doing and thought it would be helpful to share.  I ended up using a [permutation importance](https://www.kaggle.com/ourique/permutation-importance) module from the [eli5 package](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blackbox/permutation_importance.html).  It most easily works with a scikit-learn model.  Luckily, Keras provides a [wrapper for sequential models](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/).  As shown in the code below, using it is very straightforward.

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier, KerasRegressor
import eli5
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance

def base_model():
    model = Sequential()        
    ...
    return model

X = ...
y = ...

my_model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=base_model, **sk_params)    
my_model.fit(X,y)

perm = PermutationImportance(my_model, random_state=1).fit(X,y)
eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = X.columns.tolist())
```

Comment: this line  *eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = X.columns.tolist())* 
 returns error:   *AttributeError: module 'eli5' has no attribute 'show_weights'*

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File in <module> eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names =  col) AttributeError: module 'eli5' has no attribute 'show_weights'

Comment: Not sure what the issue is.  It works on my computer and is listed in documentation here: https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html  Do you have the most recent version?

Comment: I had a chat with the eli5 developer; It turns out that the error: AttributeError: module 'eli5' has no attribute 'show_weights' is only displayed if I'm not using iPython Notebook, which I wasn't at the time of when the post was published. Strange phenomenon, but I will test it out with IPython installed.

Comment: eli5.show_weights outputs an HTML object, so it will only be displayed in iPython (jupyter) Notebook.

Comment: why the sum of all the permutations (perm.feature_importances_) are not equal to one?

Comment: I would like to add that `eli5` currently only supports 2d arrays. If your model uses 3d layers like `GRU` or `LSTM`, `eli5` will not work for you. You need to use another library like `SHAP` instead.

Answer (score 19):

This is a relatively old post with relatively old answers, so I would like to offer another suggestion of using [`SHAP`](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) to determine feature importance for your Keras models. `SHAP` offers support for both 2d and 3d arrays compared to `eli5` which currently only supports 2d arrays (so if your model uses layers which require 3d input like `LSTM` or `GRU`, `eli5` will not work).

Here is the [link](https://github.com/slundberg/shap#deep-learning-example-with-deepexplainer-tensorflowkeras-models) to an example of how `SHAP` can plot the feature importance for your `Keras` models, but in case it ever becomes broken some sample code and plots are provided below as well (taken from said link):

```py
import shap

# load your data here, e.g. X and y
# create and fit your model here

# load JS visualization code to notebook
shap.initjs()

# explain the model's predictions using SHAP
# (same syntax works for LightGBM, CatBoost, scikit-learn and spark models)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)

# visualize the first prediction's explanation (use matplotlib=True to avoid Javascript)
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:], X.iloc[0,:])

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X, plot_type="bar")
```

[image]

Comment: Error when using `DeepExplainer`: `keras is no longer supported, please use tf.keras instead.`

Comment: Error when using `TreeExplainer` `SHAPError: Model type not yet supported by TreeExplainer: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>`

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax I assume you are trying to use `Sequential` layer from Keras. Can you try importing `Sequential` using this instead? `from tensorflow.keras import Sequential`

Comment: @jarrettyeo, `from tensorflow.keras import Sequential` still doesn't work. I get the error: `Exception: Model type not yet supported by TreeExplainer: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>`

Comment: @user5305519 can you provide the solution to any of the above questions?  I am also getting this error:  Exception: Model type not yet supported by TreeExplainer: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional'>

Comment: @Kermit refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/72480697/13046931

Answer (score 7):

At the moment Keras doesn't provide any functionality to extract the feature importance.

You can check this previous question:
[Keras: Any way to get variable importance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119207/keras-any-way-to-get-variable-importance)

or the related GoogleGroup: [Feature importance](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/uwQnMC333IE)

Spoiler: In the GoogleGroup someone announced an open source project to solve this issue..

Comment: Why not do Feature Importance with sklearn_RandomForest ?

Answer (score 3):

A lame way is to get weights for each neuron in each layer and show/stack them together.

```
feature_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['feature','layer','neuron','weight','abs_weight'])

for i,layer in enumerate(model.layers[:-1]): 
    w = layer.get_weights()
    w = np.array(w[0])
    n = 0
    for neuron in w.T:
        for f,name in zip(neuron,X.columns):
            feature_df.loc[len(feature_df)] = [name,i,n,f,abs(f)]
        
        n+=1
        
feature_df = feature_df.sort_values(by=['abs_weight'])
feature_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
feature_df = feature_df.drop(['index'], axis=1)

fig = px.bar(feature_df,x='feature',y='abs_weight',template='simple_white')
fig.show()
```

It gives something like this, x-axis is your features:

[image]