# Shap python Model type not yet supported by TreeExplainer: class 'sklearn.ensemble._stacking.StackingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning, shap

I tried to use Shap (`Tree Explainer`) for `sklearn.ensemble._stacking.StackingClassifier`

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x)
shap.initjs()
return shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[1], shap_values[1], x)
```

But I got an error:
`Model type not yet supported by TreeExplainer: <class 'sklearn.ensemble._stacking.StackingClassifier'>`

How can I use shap `force_plot` for sklearn `StackingClassifier`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TreeExplainer` only works on tree-based models themselves, not on pipelines or metamodels that end with a tree-based model.

If you want interpretability in terms of your original features, you will need to use the base Explainer class (or equivalently, the `KernelExplainer` class). Unfortunately, this will be approximate and more computationally expensive.